# Insert into Queue, and periodically pop n elements and perform an action

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to write a program that:

- is multi threaded
- shares a queue among processes
- i.e., allows multiple threads to write to the same queue
- periodically pops the first n elements and  calls a function on those elements
- If a kill command is inserted, the function returns

UPDATE: I got the desired behavior with by declaring a queue and by not passing it into any functions. is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

```py
def poll():
    chunk_size = 10
    debug = True
    f = sum
    sleep  = 2
    while True:
        print("SIZE", q.qsize())
        if not q.empty():
            data = [q.get() for i in range(0, min(q.qsize(), chunk_size))]
            if data[-1] == "KILL":
                if debug:
                    print("[!] Kill command recieved.", len(data))
                return 
            print(f(data))
        if debug:
            print("[!] Sleeping ")
        time.sleep(sleep)
def insert():
    q.put(time.time())
    time.sleep(1)
    q.put(time.time())


q = Manager().Queue()
p = Process(target=poll)
p.start()
j = [Process(target=insert()) for i in range(10) ]
for i in j:
    i.start()
for i in j:
    i.join()

q.put("KILL")
print("SHOULD STOP")
p.join()
print("DONE!")
```

Comment: if you really want to make a multithreaded program, use `threading.Thread` and not `Process`.

Comment: Im open to this-- but isn't it significantly slower to use threading.thread?